# Cities with a larger number of acquirers than startups

Tags: python, sql

My query below produces no output. I'm simply trying to group by city, then get only the city names of the groups which satisfy my "having" condition. What is wrong here?

```
    create view que as

    select acquirer_city
    from acquisitions as A
    group by acquirer_city
    having count(distinct company_name) < count(distinct acquirer_name)
```

Comment: Are you running the query or the `create` statement (which would not produce results)? If you are running the query, maybe you have no data that meets the conditions? Try changing the less-than to a greater-or-equal sign to see if you get data back.

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL is creating a view, not running a query. If you then run

```
select * from que
```

You will see the content of the view. However, if you are not wanting to create a view (to be used later), then just remove the first line. It will then run the query and return the results.